# Background Location Updates are stopping with background task issue identified in debugger

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been using background location updating since iOS 9 with no problems and this issue just showed up now in iOS 13.  The debugger console identifies this issue when the app enters the background: "Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 3 (0x3), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug."

Here's how boilerplate code for location updates in the background:

First, the code in the AppDelegate:

```
if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
   locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
   locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
}
```

The info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>"MY APP" is optimized to run in the background as well as when your using it directly.  For best results, choose ALWAYS.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>"MY APP" is optimized to run in the background.  Please choose ALLOW.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Please choose ALLOW WHILE USING APP.  "MY APP" needs to use your location to get its altitude data.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
```

As far as I can tell there's nothing that should be causing this issue.  And why it's just started makes no sense.

Comment: I get that message despite having an app that doesn't do anything in the background. AFAICT, it's some sort of iOS 13 issue.  It doesn't seem to cause any problems though (aside from being annoying) and didn't prevent the app from passing review.

Comment: I guess the bigger issue is that location updating is being stopped in the background and the only info i have to debug with is that console message.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has improved the way of asking for user's location permission in order to make it more user friendly in iOS 13.

There's nothing wrong with your code and you shouldn't change anything (as you are already using `requestAlwaysAuthorization()` and `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates`.)

Basically what is happening is: until iOS 12, the user would be asked for permission on location and could choose to Always allow, Allow once and to not allow at all. 
In iOS 13, the options are Allow when is use, allow once, and not allow.

Then, iOS itself will ask for the "Always" permission when it judges necessary (aka, when your app enter in background and tries to perform some action that needs the location info).